# Не получается проверить номер телефона на валидность

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, html5, форма

Всем привет. Есть поле для заполнения номера мобильного телефона `<input type="tel" name="phone">`, в котором можно вводить телефон как в междунароlном формате (+375111111, +375 111 111, +375-111-111), так и в локальном (8111111, 8 11 11, 8-11-11), т.е. допускается использовать цифры, пробел, дефис и плюс, но у меня проверка не проходит - пишу:

```
<input type="tel" name="phone" value="" size="40" required data-validation-regexp="\+?\(?\d{2,4}\)?[\d\s-]{3,}">
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: В регекспе, вероятно. Если вдруг пройдет валидация текста `+dddddddd`, нужно задвоить обратные слэши.

Comment: @Vesper не, на `+dddddddd` тоже ругается...

Comment: А как насчет [`^(?:8[ -]?\d{2}[ -]?\d{2}(?:[ -]?\d{2})?|\+\d{3}[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{3})$`](https://regex101.com/r/bS6gE1/1)?

Comment: @stribizhev хорошо, только еще осталось, чтобы человек ввел минимум 7 цифр, а не 5 как сейчас

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры.

Comment: 55555, 77 777 - такие телефоны прокатывают

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="tel" name="phone" value="" size="40" pattern="\+?\(?\d{2,4}\)?[\d\s-]{3,}">
```

Нужен pattern, а не required data-validation-regexp.

Comment: только еще видимо сам патерн неправильный

Comment: Он кажется с инструкции гугля взят ;)